# How to get evenly spaced list items?

Tags: css, formatting

I'm wrestling with a thumbnail list that won't tap out ...

It's a `UL` with thumbnails and a link to the thumbnail's page, but depending on the length of the anchor text, it's causing the spacing between the `LI`'s to be different in each item.

Screenshot:

[image]

The current CSS is:

```
.top-posts {
    padding: 0 0 0 65px;
    position: relative;
}

#ajax_hits_counter_popular_posts_widget-2.widget li {
    background: none;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}

#ajax_hits_counter_popular_posts_widget-2.widget li a {
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
}

#ajax_hits_counter_popular_posts_widget-2.widget img {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    border: 4px solid #353434;
}
```

The HTML is a pretty simple:

```
<li>
    <div class="top-posts">
        <a href="{permalink}" title="{post_title}">{thumbnail-50x50}{post_title}</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

I'd post a JSFiddle example, but since it's a template it turns out to be a ton of code, and even then, the issue is not appearing quite the same in JSF as it is on the live site, so I figure it's probably better to post the link instead (it's the Top Posts list at the bottom right): [example here](http://meanwhileinamerica.com)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a minimum height to the `<li>`:

```
#ajax_hits_counter_popular_posts_widget-2.widget li {
    background: none;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    min-height: 68px;
}
```

The height of 68px accounts for the 10px bottom padding on the `li` and the absolutely positioned `img` height of 50px with it's 8px (2 x 4px) border.

The `li` height collapses to the size of the text as the image is absolutely positioned and doesn't add to the height of the `li`.

Comment: Aha, using your min-height tip, I change my above code to:
`margin: 0 0 15px 0 !important;
padding: 0;
min-height: 50px;`
And it looks great now, ty.

Comment: Awesome. Be wary of absolutely positioned elements. Remember to up vote and accept!

Comment: Yes, I had also used a float: left on the img and it basically looked the same, so I just used this one, lol. If it causes any issues down the road I'll make some switches. I'll accept once SO allows me to, lol.